# Recover database with no backups

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

I want to know if there is a way to revover the state of a database at a certain date. Unfortunately I don't have a backup.

Answer (score 11):

Without backups of any kind, there is nothing you can do - since previous state has been wiped away by checkpoints (even in full recovery, [it acts like simple recovery until you've bothered to take a backup](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-is-that-database-really-in-the-full-recovery-mode/)). This situation is precisely what backups are for. If you jump out of a plane without a parachute, don't bother looking for the ripcord...

Comment: i KNOW THERE I A WAY TO OPERATE WITH LOG SERVER IN ORDER TO RECUPERATE SOMETHIG. iS IT WRONG??

Comment: @Simon sorry I don't understand your question. Also please stop yelling.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron said above there are very few things you can do here.

Why do you need to recover database to a previous state? If you deleted some data and want to undo transactions you can probably recover some data if your database was in full recovery mode.

If this is the case you can try reading transaction log using [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/) or [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)