# Restoring Deleted Database In SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to restore the deleted database in SQL Server 2005?

The accident operation by someone: right click database > deleted. How to restore it?

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just have the latest backup at Thursday. The Friday the database has deleted, and all my updated date at Friday gone. Any idea? help

Comment: lol,:) if he had backup he wouldn't have posted this question i guess [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675969/recover-database-with-no-backups)

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi Yes, except the OP actually *did* have an older backup which changes the question entirely :)

Comment: Accidents are less likely to happen if you use permissions to restrict actions....